# How do I copy a pre-existing sqlite database file from assets to database folder?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having real trouble getting my app working and I've spent hours trying without success.

I create a database which has a table containing 1000s of pre-existing rows (done on my desktop). I don't want to populate the app db when the app runs because of the amount of data. So I intend to have the app deployment copy the existing file from the assets folder into the database folder.  This *must* be a re-occuring pattern in people's development.

The code for achieving this is in part from this link:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Sorry for pasting a bit of code, I don't normally do this but I've spent hours on this with no solution in sight.

My main activity is like so:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            try {
            new DbHelper(this).createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                        
            //....   
        }
}
```

In the DbHelper, copyDataBase is called to copy the asset db over.
When I open up the database no tables exist and only the android_metadata table exists. So somehow the copy failed???

The DbHelper is like so:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG= "DbHelper";

    static final String DB_NAME = "mydatabase.sqlite";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_PATH = "";

    private Context myContext;

    public DbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,  DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;

        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Copying database...");
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getWritableDatabase();
        }

    }

    public boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            Log.d(TAG, "db exists");
            }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
             //database does't exist yet.
            Log.d(TAG, "db doesn't exist");

         }

         if(checkDB != null){
             checkDB.close();
         }

         return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close(); 
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed any light onto why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my code that does basically the same thing, you should have:

```
InputStream = myContext.getResources().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
```

I am not sure offhand what the difference is between `Context.getAssets` and `Resources.getAssets`, but give it a try.

Comment: Hi, revisited this today. The file is actually getting copied over and is 1441792 bytes long in the DDMS, so I can see a large file there. However, when I pull it down, open it in Sqlite3 command line tool or the FireFox SQLManager add-in, it only has the android_metadata table in there. When I binary compare both files the original AND file that I pulled down from the DDMS they are the same! What is going on here?!?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I have exactly the same problem. Did You fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the onCreate method of your SQLiteOpenHelper might not be where you want to do the copy.  You want to copy the file before trying to open/create it.

For debugging, I have done this from my app's startup code numerous times and it's worked fine:

```
    copyFile("/sdcard/dbs/latest_database.db", context.getDatabasePath("DatabaseNameHere").getPath());
```

(copyFile simply being a little helper function that does what you'd expect.)

You should be able to tweak that to copy it from your assets dir instead of sdcard.

Note that when I was doing this, I was copying a database that I had extracted from a previous build of the app.  If you're trying to copy over a database that you made with a non-android sqlite tool, you may need to add an android_metadata table first.  As far as I've ever seen, that's just a single column ("locale") and a single row (eg "en_US").